# How to display the places without using google places api?

Tags: android, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I am developing an android app for blind people where I want to display the nearby locations and bus stops to the user.

I don't want to use google places api but I need to input the name,address,type,latitude and longitude of the stores in a MySQL database and then use this database to send relevant data to the android app.

Can you post some tutorials where I can learn to do this.

Comment: The problem is that you don't know any other sources of info about public places, or that you don't know how to implement the whole thing? The question seems ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to get data from MySQL database use it in android

here is [tutorial1](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-google-map-v2-part-1.html) and [tutorial2](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-google-map-v2-part-3-add.html) what you need and [refrance link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/?hl=fr-FR)

adding marker:

```
float lat = -23.4456f;
float lng = 45.44334f;
LatLng point = new LatLng(lat, lng);

MAP.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("my place name"));
```

[also check this for more detail](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) and here is [best detail as per you requirement](http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/mapOverlayDemo.html) (which is not in google map v2 but you get more idea).